# Remove object from array based on index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've already looked at [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript) but this doesn't quite answer my question as I can't get it to work.

I have an array

```js
var cardDeck = [{
    "card": "Ace",
    "suit": "Diamonds",
    "color": "Red",
    "eval": 1,
    "altEval":11
  },
     {
    "card": "Ace",
    "suit": "Spades",
    "color":"Black",
    "eval": 1,
    "altEval":11
  },
     {
    "card": "Ace",
    "suit": "Clubs",
    "color":"Black",
    "eval": 1,
    "altEval":11
  },
     {
    "card": "Ace",
    "suit": "Hearts",
    "color":"Red",
    "eval": 1,
    "altEval":11
  }
    ]
;

console.log(cardDeck);
```

and I want to remove create a new array with one of the objects.

In plain language, this is a card deck with 4 aces, I want to take out one of the aces and put it in a new array (`playerhand`)

```js
///
var cardDeck = [{
    "card": "Ace",
    "suit": "Diamonds",
    "color": "Red",
    "eval": 1,
    "altEval":11
  },
     {
    "card": "Ace",
    "suit": "Spades",
    "color":"Black",
    "eval": 1,
    "altEval":11
  },
     {
    "card": "Ace",
    "suit": "Clubs",
    "color":"Black",
    "eval": 1,
    "altEval":11
  },
     {
    "card": "Ace",
    "suit": "Hearts",
    "color":"Red",
    "eval": 1,
    "altEval":11
  }
    ]
;

//console.log(cardDeck);

var playerhand = cardDeck.splice[0];

console.log(playerhand)
```

The above code logs `undefined`.

```js
var array = [2, 5, 9];
console.log(array)

array.splice(array, [1]);

//array = [2, 9]
console.log(array);
```

The above works but the following does not:

```js
var array = [{
    "card": "Ace",
    "suit": "Diamonds",
    "color": "Red",
    "eval": 1,
    "altEval":11
  },
     {
    "card": "Ace",
    "suit": "Spades",
    "color":"Black",
    "eval": 1,
    "altEval":11
  },
     {
    "card": "Ace",
    "suit": "Clubs",
    "color":"Black",
    "eval": 1,
    "altEval":11
  },
     {
    "card": "Ace",
    "suit": "Hearts",
    "color":"Red",
    "eval": 1,
    "altEval":11
  }
    ];
console.log(array);

array.splice(array, [0]);


console.log(array);
```

Comment: `cardDeck.splice[0]`, `splice(array, [0])`, ..., these all don't make much semantical sense in almost all scenarios. Please read another JS tutorial, i think it would be the most beneficial.

Comment: `.splice` is a *method*, you call it the same way you call functions and other methods with `()` at the end. `cardDeck.splice[0];` doesn't work that way. And `array.splice(array, [0]);` doesn't pass the correct arguments to the method.

Comment: Please go through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: that helps with splice, guess i need to find the correct method.

Comment: `splice` is the correct method to remove an item from an array at a specific index and return it in a new array.

Comment: The linked question's accepted answer formulates the `splice` method correctly, and explains what the parameters do and what is returned, in addition to linking to the same resource as @AyushGupta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array.splice(0,1,"") this will work fine.

splice method takes as array.splice(index, howmany, item1, ....., itemX) 
index to delete, how many from the given index to delete and the 3 parameter is what to add in place of that(which you can skip)

Comment: thank you!, i noticed this doesn't change the length, (is still 4 items) i guess what i was wanting to do was more like pop(), but with a specific index

Comment: this will change the length just use array.splice(0,1) .This will remove the one elemnt form 0th index and will not add anything in that place.

Comment: you're very kind to have helped a nub :)